# How to set random XY coordinates of a turtle with a constraint of patch variable

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have patches with a variable called ID and population, imported from a GIS vector. I requested that the patches sprout the population, the turtles, at the centroid of each feature ID. But I would like the turtles not to overlap, to be assigned random xy coodinates for each turtle within a constraint of the patch ID variable.
For example, a turtle spouted in a centroid of a patch ID = 1 could be in any patch with ID = 1, but not patches with other IDs.

```
> patches-own [ID centroid? pop]
> turtles-own [tID]
>
> ask patches with [ID >= 1] [sprout (pop * 0.1) [
>     set tID ID
>     let mypatch one-of patches with [ID = tID]
>     move-to mypatch   ]]
```

An error saying that I can't use tID as a patch context, because tID is turtle-only shows up.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `tID` in the `with` statement that's confusing NetLogo.  You can work around that by setting a local variable to hold the value:

```
patches-own [ ID ]
turtles-own [ tID ]

to test1
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set ID random 3 ]
  ask patches with [ID >= 1] [
    sprout (random 10) [
      set tID ID
      let tID-local tID
      let mypatch one-of patches with [ID = tID-local]
      move-to mypatch   
  ]]
end
```

But I'm not sure that's actually what you want.  You're already asking the patches with the `ID >= 1` to `sprout` the turtles, meaning they're going to be on those patches already.  Try this out and see if it looks right:

```
to test2
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set ID random 3 ]
  ask patches with [ID >= 1] [
    sprout (random 10) [
      set tID ID
  ]]
end
```

I could be totally wrong and you do mean to shuffle the population among the same-ID patches, in which case ignore my second part!